# Hide the extra row at the bottom in a DataGridview in a Winform Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have binded a datagridview to a datatable. But the gridview displays an extra empty  row at the bottom ? How should I hide it ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The extra row is to manually add a line to your datagridview. If you don't need it you can disable it by disallowing the user to add rows:

```
this.dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Comment: I spent an hour hunting through XML-parsing code, thinking something was being imported incorrectly...thanks! :)

Comment: I found this looking for an answer to just a DataGrid. It's property equivalent is `CanUserAddRows`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
CurrencyManager cm = myGrid.BindingContext[myGrid.DataSource, myGrid.DataMember] 
                     as CurrencyManager;
DataView dv = cm.List as DataView;
dv.AllowNew = false;
```